# How did Red get approval for rehabilitation?

Tags: character, the-shawshank-redemption

In *Shawshank Redemption*, Red receives parole after serving 40 years in Shawshank. In the beginning of movie it is shown that Red's plea for rehabilitation got rejected multiple times. When Andy breaks-out of Shawshank, it gives hope to Red but in his interaction with the prison authority Red shows no interest in getting out. So how did Red get approval for rehabilitation?